# Why is require() undefined during karma tests but is ok during runtime?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, jasmine, karma-runner

So I'm working on Angular 2 app, which is being written in TypeScript, and wrote some unit tests with Jasmine (also in TypeScript). After compilation all imports are translated to `require()`. When I run my app in the browser everything works fine, but when I try to run unit test with `karma` it says `Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined`. I've googled that and folks say it's because `karma` runs test in browser and browser doesn't know about `require()`, but why it works ok during runtime then?

Comment: `require` works in a Node.js environment. Is that your case ? You're not mentioning that at all.

Comment: This is the way I start the app `"start": "tsc && concurrently \"tsc -w\" \"lite-server\" ",` (this line is in `package.json`) and this is the way tests start `"test": "tsc && concurrently \"tsc -w\" \"karma start karma.conf.js\"",` (also in `package.json`). So you mean this `lite-server`, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update** - pretty much rewriting the answer based on changed assumptions.

As you've found elsewhere, the reason karma tests fail on `require()` is because karma runs the test in a browser.  `require()` is not supported by any of the major browsers.

You ask, in that case why does it work at runtime?  The answer, based on comments, is that you're not running in a browser at runtime.  You're running in node.js, which *does* support `require()`.

As I noted in the original version of my reply, tools like webpack and browserify exist specifically to allow code that uses `require()` to run in a browser.  They do require some set-up, so if you don't intend to run in a browser you probably don't want to mess with them.

And so you probably don't want to run your tests in a browser either, since your test environment should match your runtime environment as closely as possible.  In my experience the main thing karma gives you is the ability to run your tests in various browsers in an automated way, but if the runtime you care about is node then that doesn't help you.

Comment: I've seen some info about it, but it seems like I have to do a gigantic amount of configuring to make it work, while when I start the app from `npm` (starting line is `"start": "tsc && concurrently \"tsc -w\" \"lite-server\" ",`), it works ok and I don't have to do anything.